# Bottom overflow due to bottom navigation bar and tab Bar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver, flutter-listview

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);

    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
     key: _scaffoldKeyProfilePage,

      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
 child:RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: _onRefresh,
        child: NestedScrollView(
          
            headerSliverBuilder: (context, _) {
              return [
                SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                 [                 BuildMainProfile(
              ....//
                 ),
                 Padding(
                ...//another design 
                 ), 
                
              ];
            },
            // You tab view goes here
            body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: 'A'),
                Tab(text: 'B'),
              ],
                ),
                Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  BuildPost(,

                  ),
                 BuildWings()
                ],
              ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),),
      ),
```

}[image]

Above is the example of error which I am getting

 error:A RenderFlex overflowed by 48 pixels on the bottom.

How to solve this issue? Tried using expanded on TabBar and giving flex of 1 to tab bar and flex of 10 to tabView , but with that tab bar shrinks on scrolling down.

Here below is the code for tabBar view A and B is even similar

```
class BuildPost extends StatefulWidget {
  final String uid;

  const BuildPost({
    Key key,
    @required this.uid,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _BuildPostState createState() => _BuildPostState();
}

class _BuildPostState extends State<BuildPost> {
  List<Post> _post = [];

  getUsersPost() async {
    final database = FirestoreDatabase();
    List<Post> _postModel = await database.getUsersPost(widget.uid);
    setState(() {
      _post = _postModel.toList();
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getUsersPost();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _post.isEmpty
        ? Container(
            height: 500,
            width: double.infinity,
          )
        : GestureDetector(
            child: Directionality(
                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                child: AnimationLimiter(
                  child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    crossAxisCount: 3,
                    itemCount: _post.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredGrid(
                        position: index,
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                        columnCount: 3,
                        child: SlideAnimation(
                          verticalOffset: 50.0,
                          child: FadeInAnimation(
                              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                              child: BuildData(
                                totalPost: _post.length,
                                postList: _post,
                                index: index,
                                post: _post[index],
                              )),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    staggeredTileBuilder: (index) => StaggeredTile.count(
                        index % 7 == 0 ? 2 : 1,
                        index % 7 == 0 ? (2.1) : (1.05)),
                    mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                  ),
                )),
          );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have managed to re-create the same UI without issue, could you please give more code for the Tabs so I can test more.

Comment: @JacksonLee I have added the code for the Tabs

Comment: I think your headerSliverBuilder is too tall, leaving to enough space for the TabBar in the body.

Comment: @spkersten that space is deliberately tall, which is dynamic. Where the user can put their bio.

Comment: I think the body is supposed to be some scrollable widget (ListView, CustomScrollView). Can you put the TabBar at the bottom of headerSliverBuilder?

Comment: I can't add the tab bar at the bottom of headerSliverBuilder, because when we scroll tab bar would be hidden and wouldn't stick to the top. Any other way out? My layout is almost similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/59981330/13406343

Comment: Thanks, I  just need the model for Post and BuildData widget - If its easier, drop the files into my onedrive - https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoUkF50a_XNzgX0ocwbBGiaqELFQ?e=n1j4Bk

Comment: BuildData just contain the code for the grid ,which is nothing more than a rounded container with further gesture detector property. And Post is just a model class for the usersPost from Firestore.

Comment: why is the Expanded is needed as the parent of the TabBarView? what does removing does?

Comment: Removing Expanded gives an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the body height of `NestedScrollView` is from 0 to MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, while your **TabBar** inside the column make it layout a minimal height of TabBar.

### Move TabBar inside builder

Form the example of [NestedScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html), you can see the TabBar is inside headerSliverBuilder. You can simply move the **TabBar** inside it (wrap a `SliverToBoxAdapter`or `SliverAppBar` to make it sliver).

Then you can remove the `Column` and `Expand` Widget above the **TabBarView**

```
child: NestedScrollView(
  headerSliverBuilder: (context, _) {
    return [
      SliverList( 
       ...
      ),
      SliverAppBar(
        pinned: true,
        primary: false,  // no reserve space for status bar
        toolbarHeight: 0,  // title height = 0
        bottom: TabBar(
          tabs: [
            Tab(text: 'A'),
            Tab(text: 'B'),
          ],
        ),
      )
    ];
  }
  body: TabBarView(
    children: [
     ...
```

[image]

Comment: Hey the issue with the first solution is I want the tab bar to be pinned +the issue with your first code is similar to this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qTJa37BRax4rQv7egdptynRk0lHRMz8q/view the issue is , if you clearly see when we scroll up after reaching the bottom of tabView, the grid of tab view remains inside the headerSliverBuilder. headerSliver starts showing its component before we reach the top of the grid of tab View. And the issue with 2nd solution is ,TabBar gets shrink and deshrink on scrolling

Comment: I update with a `ListView` with `ConstrainedBox` solution. Check it out if it fit your situation.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't fit in, Now the issue is due to list view, the  Grid scroll in its own position, and seems like there's no use of using NestedScrollView. Demo is here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OrwxdvXiLo49eUP8ulC_tjVT1gmXoSyC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: No, I haven't set any scroller inside my NestedScrollView

Comment: I see. I change the first solution using `SliverAppBar` with pinned is true. Is the layout fit?

Comment: Due to this SliverAppBar, there's a lot of unwanted space due to leading and title and the issue of  "When we scroll up after reaching the bottom of tabView, the grid of tab view remains inside the headerSliverBuilder. headerSliver starts showing its component before we reach the top of the grid of tab View" -remains still there

Comment: I remove the unwanted answer and update with SliverAppBar part. You can actually remove unwanted space (please see the update). I am quite a little bit lost what you really want in result. Your original question is the overflowing issue, but no much describing what your layout should be.

Comment: Could you please provide the code for the grid of yours, because I am still facing the same issue here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1164KZyVIVgoC0UMDj1jG2-nyZykqNO9E/view?usp=sharing . We could see we never get to see the 0th grid again on scrolling.

Comment: ok, I got where the issue was, I was having My nestedScrollViews property floatHeaderSlivers: true,

Comment: Isn't this just the same answer as I gave?

Comment: spkersten I think u are right. I haven't notice after trying so many options, the final one is like yours... Let me give you a upvote for your foresight.

Answer (score 0):

The `body` property of `NestedScrollView` gets a tight height constraint equal to the space left over by `headerSliverBuilder` (considering the scroll position). In your code, you've as body a `Column` widget with a fixed height (the `TabBar`) widget in there. So when the height constraint of body gets smaller than the `TabBar` height, it will overflow the `Column`.

So in `body`, there must be a widget that can shrink to zero height, most likely a scrollable (`ListView`, `CustomScrollView`). In your case, you can move the `TabBar` to the bottom of `headerSliverBuilder`, wrapping it with:

```dart
SliverPersistentHeader(
  pinned: true,
  delegate: SimpleHeaderDelegate(
    child: TabBar(...),
  ),
)
```

using:

```
class SimpleHeaderDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  SimpleHeaderDelegate({@required this.child});

  final PreferredSizeWidget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) => child;

  @override
  double get maxExtent => child.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  double get minExtent => child.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SimpleHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) => oldDelegate.child != child;
}
```

Comment: I can't add the tab bar at the bottom of headerSliverBuilder, because when we scroll tab bar would be hidden and wouldn't stick to the top.

Comment: I tried this but it has affected the UI design and scrolling isn't proper now if you could please check it out    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qTJa37BRax4rQv7egdptynRk0lHRMz8q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't see much wrong in that gif. Maybe you want to give child in `SimpleHeaderDelegate` a white background?

Comment: the issue is , if you clearly see when we scroll up after reaching the bottom of tabView, the grid of tab view remains inside the headerSliverBuilder. headerSliver starts showing its component before we reach the top of the grid of tab View.

Comment: @kanwarmanraj Perhaps because you have set `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` for that grid?

Comment: Actually no, I have set  physics: ScrollPhysics()

Answer (score 0):

See SingleChildScrollView class, Expanding content to fit the viewport:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).